# Laravel - Check if user is authenticated on another server

Tags: laravel, authentication

Let say I have a laravel site on a host and another host just for storing some specific files. In second host I want to check if user is authenticated on laravel site and then I gave him/her access to the file. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You could pretty much just use normal PHP code for that, without having to touch the Laravel framework on your other server.

For example, create your own custom cookie or session variable that contains a token from authentication. Make the logic something like `$authToken = md5($user->username) . "." . md5($user->password);`, then just add it to a cookie or the `$_SESSION[]` variable.

From here, create a small backend on the other server that you use for storage, and do something like this.

```
<?php
/////////////
/**
 * Here there should be database connection logic.
 */
/////////////
$posts = (object) $_POST;

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST")
{
    $postArray = [
        'authToken',
        'user'
    ];

    foreach($postArray as $post)
    {
        if (!isset($_POST[$post]))
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    $query = htmlspecialchars("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=" . $posts->user);

    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

    $row = mysqli_fetch_all($result);

    $db_stack = md5($row['username']) . "." . md5($row['password']);
    if ($posts->authToken != $db_stack)
    {
        return false;
    }

    // Return the requested file here.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If (Auth::check()) $file = file_get_contents($urlToFile);

Comment: How connect second host to laravel site?